# Concatenate HTML variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, variables, flask

I'm actually stuck on a problem,

I'm working with Flask. When rendering my template, flask pass two variable, `type` and `content` (`return render_template('detail.html', content=content_str, id=id, type=type_str)`). In my template I need to display a Form generated depending on the type variable using javascript.

To get the form I got to do something like :

`var json = (' {{ reg.JsonSchema.get("port")|tojson }} ')`

`reg` is defined in my html using a `@app.context_processor` but not directly in js because between `<script> </script>`

As you see the type (here port) is hardcoded. I tried things like :

`var json = (' {{ reg.JsonSchemaMappingTable.get({{ type }})|tojson }} ')` but it doesn't work !

Someone got an Idea of how to achieve this ? I would like to avoid doing something like if type == "..." : ...

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Where does `type` come from?

Comment: Also, JSON is a valid Javascript literal. You don't need to put that into a Javascript string literal and then presumably `JSON.parse` it. Just `var foo = {{ bar|tojson }};` will do just fine. In fact, it will do *better* if your values contain quotes or other special characters.

Comment: Can't you just use `reg.JsonSchema.get(type)`?

Comment: @deceze `type` and `content` come from `return render_template('detail.html', content=content_str, id=id, type=type_str)` . I tried to do it first, but it was a failure. :(



@Nick I can't since I'm in a `<script>`  and `reg` isn't defined here. `reg`is defined in the `base.html` (which is extended by the page I'm working on) using a `@app.context_processor`

Comment: That all seems like very relevant information to put into the question…

Comment: I've modified the question !